# Couldn't install RVM and Ruby on Mountain Lion

Tags: ruby, macos, installation, rvm, osx-mountain-lion

I tried all of the solution at StackOverflow and none of them worked for me. I tried with following command:

```
rvm get head; rvm install 1.9.3 --debug
```

and the output can be found here: http://pastie.org/7189647

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: what is in `/Users/aslam/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p392/make.log` also your problem looks like you use `zsh` and hit known bug: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/1665 - temporary switching to `bash` would show the real problem and break the installer earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the two commands separately? It appears the `rvm get head` portion of the command worked. Try running `rvm install 1.9.3` or `rvm install 1.9.3-p392`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I fixed the problem.

1. Open the Xcode 4.6 or 4.6.1 and go to Preference -> Downloads and install 'Commandline tools".
2. Open the terminal and type

   `\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails --autolibs=enabled`

as instructed in the RVM site. It works like flawless.